# UITableViewController isn't pushing views onto the stack

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a UITableViewController that has a UISearchbar in its header view. When the user searches, my UITableView populates with the results. I want to push a new view controller onto the stack when the user selects a result.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

        WatchlistSheetView* watchlistSheetView = [[WatchlistSheetView alloc] initWithNibName:@"WatchlistSheetView" bundle:nil];
        watchlistSheetView.symbol = cell.textLabel.text;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:watchlistSheetView animated:YES];
        [watchlistSheetView release];

        //[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }     
}
```

The following doesn't push a view controller onto the stack. Nothing happens. How can I resolve?

Comment: Could you confirm that watchlistSheetView is not nil after this call and that self.navigationController is not nil? In overall this code look fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that `self.navigationController` is nil, so that the message `pushViewController` is sent nowhere.

To fix this, you can create a `UINavigationController` in your `application:didFinishLaunching` and push your table view controller on to it as its root controller, along these lines:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    UINavigationController* navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];

   ....
   [navigation pushViewController:yourTableViewController animated:NO];
   ...
   [window addSubview:[navigation view]];
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

or you could use `initWithRootController` to initialize the navigation view controller with your table view controller.

Comment: This UITableViewController is being presented modally. Does this mean I don't have a UINavigationController? Where can I set this up?

Comment: the code in my answer explains what you should do to set up a navigation controller. If you have not created a navigation controller, either by code or in IB, then you do not have it and you need creating it. Best thing, create it in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` like I showed in my answer. If you need your UI to be modal, you could present the navigation controller modally, but first I would do it the "normal" way.

Comment: I do have a navigation controller. My app is a UITabBarController app, that contains UINavigationControllers for each tab. One of the tabs, launches another UITableView modally. This is where I am having the problem. Maybe I need to get the parentViewController's navigation bar?

Comment: do you want a navigation controller *inside* of the modal view? this is also possible... also you could push the new view onto the modal controller's parent, but I am not sure of the results if you do this while the modal is displayed...

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are calling self when referencing your navigation controller. Did you actually allocate a navigation controller and assign it to self?